# Using Solr 3.6.1, Arabic Words are not storing & indexing

Tags: php, solr, arabic

Hi Guys,

```
 I was searching an answer to insert the arabic letters using apach solr 3.6.1, used the following,

 In Schema, 

            <fieldType name="text_ar" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <!--  for any non-arabic  -->
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"   
             words="lang/stopwords_ar.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
            <!--  normalizes ﻯ to ﻱ, etc  -->
            <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
            </fieldType> 

 Output Response:

            <response>
            <lst name="responseHeader">
            <int name="status">0</int>
            <int name="QTime">8</int>
            <lst name="params">
            <str name="indent">on</str>
            <str name="start">0</str>
            <str name="q">*:*</str>
            <str name="version">2.2</str>
            <str name="rows">10</str>
            </lst>
            </lst>
            <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
            <doc>
            <str name="company_name">?????</str>
            <str name="id">1</str>
            <arr name="search_supplier_keyword">
            <str>?????</str>
            </arr>
            <str name="supplier_name">?????</str>
            </doc>
            </result>
            </response>
```

I Was'nt able to store arabic words instead it shows question mark as (?????).Is there anything i am really missing here? is there ? Please help me here and the possible solution.

Thanks,
 ABS

Comment: Please do not double post

Answer (score 0):

In solr 3.3 we are using the below schema for arabic words and its working great.
same can be helpful for u also.

Schema:

```
<fieldType name="text_arabic" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Output:

```
 <arr name="Education_arabic">
  <str>مهندس مدنى خبرة لا تقل عن 4سنوات</str>
```

Comment: Hi Jaiman,

   Still its displaying the same question mark , i have used what you have sent but it displaying the same question mark... is there anything else i have missed..

Comment: Hi Jaiman, it was my mistake actually, netbeans editor not accepting arabic words.. But notepad++ does.But Thanks really for replying my Question.